# Prove that for every $p\in N$ we have $(dF^{-1})_{F(p)}=(dF)^{-1}_p$, with $F:N\to M$ a diffeomorphism

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, jacobian

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds and $F:N\mapsto M$ a diffeomorphism. Prove that for every $p\in N$

$(dF^{-1})_{F(p)}=(dF)^{-1}_p$

---

Foremost because $F$ is  a diffeomorphism $\text{dim}N=\text{dim}M$ and the matrix $(dF)_p$ is invertible.

My idea was to take the matrix  $(dF^{-1})_{F(p)}$ and do the multiplication with $(dF)_p$, if the final product is $I_n$ then the inverse is $(dF^{-1})_{F(p)}$ as we wanted.
Here is where I stuck:

$\left [ \frac{\partial (F^i)^{-1}}{\partial x^j} \right ]\cdot \left [ \frac{\partial (F^i)}{\partial x^j} \right ]=$

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial (F^1)^{-1}}{\partial x^1}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^1)}{\partial x^1}+\frac{\partial (F^1)^{-1}}{\partial x^2}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^2)}{\partial x^1}+...+\frac{\partial (F^1)^{-1}}{\partial x^n}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^n)}{\partial x^1} &.  &.  &.  &\frac{\partial (F^1)^{-1}}{\partial x^1}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^1)}{\partial x^n}+...+\frac{\partial (F^1)^{-1}}{\partial x^n}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^n)}{\partial x^n} \\ 
 .&  .&  &  & \\ 
 .&  &  .&  & \\ 
 .&  &  &  .& \\ 
 \frac{\partial (F^n)^{-1}}{\partial x^1}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^1)}{\partial x^1}+...+\frac{\partial (F^n)^{-1}}{\partial x^n}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^n)}{\partial x^1}&  .&  .&  .& \frac{\partial (F^n)^{-1}}{\partial x^1}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^1)}{\partial x^n}+...+\frac{\partial (F^n)^{-1}}{\partial x^n}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^n)}{\partial x^n}
\end{bmatrix}

in order for the above to be $I_n$ it  must be true that $\frac{\partial (F^i)^{-1}}{\partial x^i}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^i)}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial (F^i)^{-1}\circ F^i }{\partial x^i}=1$ and the rest should be zeros

but I dont think this is correct, I have never seen $\frac{\partial (F^i)^{-1}}{\partial x^i}\cdot \frac{\partial (F^i)}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial (F^i)^{-1}\circ F^i }{\partial x^i}=1$

**Can someone clarify this for me, if my idea is correct how should I proceed ? and if it's not can you give a hint ?**

Comment: You must make use of the fact that $F^{-1}(F(x)) = x$.

Comment: @Thomas As I said above, if the product of the partials is the compositions then I am using this. That's what I am asking, how to use that.

Comment: $(F^i)^{-1}$ does not make sense, you mean $(F^{-1})^i$. Anyway, this just comes down to the chain rule. I think writing the chain rule out in coordinates is probably doing more confusion than help (and also less clear since you're omitting the points at which we're evaluating).

Comment: @Thorgott in order to apply the chain rule I must have a product of 2 functions, also I can't see how the product will eventually give me composition.

Comment: The chain rule is about compositions, not products..

Comment: @Thorgott you are right I got confused, what  I mean is that  now I have a product of partials, I don't have a composition  to use the chain rule

Comment: That's what the chain rule looks like in coordinates. It's a matrix multiplication after all. My point, however, is that you really don't need to spell it out in coordinates and should just apply the chain rule at the level of linear maps.

Comment: @Thorgott you mean something like this $I_n=\left [\delta ^i_j  \right ]=\left [ \frac{\partial {x^i} }{\partial x^j}\right ]=\left [ \frac{\partial(F^i(F^{-1})^i) }{\partial x^j} \right ]=\left [ \frac{\partial F^i(F^{-1})^i }{\partial x^j} \right ]\underbrace{\left [ \frac{\partial (F^{-1})^i }{\partial x^j} \right ]}_{(dF^{-1})}$

Comment: @Thorgott  I think I'm still missing something thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One the one hand, we have $d(F^{-1})_{F(p)}$, which is the differential of $F^{-1}:M\to N$, calculated at $F(p)\in M$. This is a map of the form $d(F^{-1})_{F(p)}:T_{F(p)}M\to T_p N$, and more precisely the one acting on tangent spaces $[\gamma]\in T_{F(p)} M$ as (I'm using parentheses to stress the order of the operation and who's who's input):
$$\color{red}{(} d(F^{-1})_{F(p)} \color{red}{)}([\gamma])
= [F^{-1}\circ \gamma] \in T_p N,$$
On the other hand, consider $dF_p^{-1}\equiv (dF_p)^{-1}$. More precisely, this is the inverse of $dF_p:T_p N\to T_{F(p)}M$, and thus $(dF_p)^{-1}:T_{F(p)}M\to T_p N$.

Using the properties of the differential operation, we have $$d(F^{-1})\circ dF = d(F^{-1}\circ F)=d(\text{id}_N) = \text{id}_{TN},
\\
dF\circ d(F^{-1}) = \text{id}_{TM.}$$
It follows that $d(F^{-1}):TM\to TN$ is the inverse operation of $dF:TN\to TM$. Considering their restricted action to specific fibers, this then in particular means that $d(F^{-1})\big|_{F(p)}\equiv (dF^{-1})_{F(p)}$ is the inverse of $dF\big|_p\equiv dF_p$. Which can be equivalently expressed writing that
$$d(F^{-1})\big|_{F(p)} = (dF\big|_p)^{-1} \equiv (dF_p)^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the functoriality of $dF_p$. I will denote $dF_p$ by $F_{*,p}$ or $F_{*}$. Once you prove the following data:

$1.$ If $id:M\rightarrow M$ denotes the identity then for each $p\in M$, $id_{*,p}=id_{T_pM}$

$2.$  $(F\circ G)_{*}=F_{*}\circ G_{*}$

You obtain the result you seek by taking $G$ to be the inverse of $F$.